# Drush on Windows 7 and WAMP

Tags: drush

Is running DRUSH on a Windows 7 64 bit machine in a WAMP dev environment worth it? I've heard there are some speed and performance issues with this set up? Will I lose any functionality with this set up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the dev version at [Drush-on-Windows-Installer GitHub](https://github.com/drushonwindows/Drush-on-Windows-Installer).

Some key functionality, such as remote sql-sync, is not working yet. You could also try running drush under Linux using a Virtual Machine on your Windows box.

Comment: Hey greg. There any advantage of using drush on powershell over drush + cygwin ?

Comment: drush work as well for my windows 7, x86.

Comment: @Chris: The main advantage of using powershell would be if you were much more comfortable with that shell.  The best shell to use with drush is MsysGit, because the others do not support git (at least not as far as I know).

Answer (score 2):

i found this excellent tutorial over the net long time ago ,
http://vimeo.com/15371661
its a bit old & before drush windows installer came out .
in this tutorial there is fine explanation how to install the drush with all the necessary components from the command line .

i hope you & others will find this useful.