# Migration from drupal to platform.sh

Tags: 7, migrations

I have developed website which is hosted on hostgator now I want to host it on platform.sh. Could anyone give me step by step procedure to migrate my website to platfrom.sh?
I am using windows 8.1 for development. Could you please explain how to use git. Could please give step by step procedure how to use it. I am on windows platform. I am bit confused how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

To migrate your existing site into Platform.sh, there are 3 components you need to import: code base, database and files.

### Import code base

If your project already uses Git you've to go to your Git project folder and add platform as a remote and push your local branch to your platform remote.

```
$ cd ~/Sites/platform
$ git remote add platform [PROJECT-ID]@git.[CLUSTER].platform.sh:[PROJECT-ID].git
$ git push platform HEAD:master
```

### Import your database

1. [Create drush alias](https://docs.platform.sh/toolstacks/php/drupal/drush/#create-drush-aliases) for your platform.sh, e.g.

   ```
   $ cd ~/.drush
   $ sudo vi platform.aliases.drushrc.php
   ```

   In your new alias file, you can create aliases for your various Platform.sh projects. For example:

   ```
   <?php
   // Platform environment
   $aliases['master'] = array(
     'uri' => 'master-[project-id].eu.platform.sh',
     'root' => '/app/public',
     'remote-host' => 'ssh.eu.platform.sh',
     'remote-user' => '[project-id]-master',
   );
   // Platform branch environment
   $aliases['BRANCHNAME'] = array(
     'uri' => 'BRANCHNAME-[project-id].eu.platform.sh',
     'root' => '/app/public',
     'remote-host' => 'ssh.eu.platform.sh',
     'remote-user' => '[project-id]-BRANCHNAME',
   );
   // Platform local environment
   $aliases['local'] = array(
     'site' => 'platform',
     'env' => 'local',
     'uri' => 'platform',
     'root' => '~/Sites/platform',
   );
   ```
2. Backup your database.

   $ drush @platform.local sql-dump > backup_database.sql
3. Export your local database and then import it into your remote Platform environment.

   ```
   $ drush @platform.local sql-dump > local_database.sql
   $ drush @platform.master sql-cli < local_database.sql
   ```
4. When the process completes, you can visit the URL of your development environment and test that the database has been properly imported.

### Import your files

1. Use drush alias to import your existing local files:

   ```
   $ drush rsync @platform.local:%files @platform.master:%files
   ```

---

The above steps assume that you're using `drush` and Git scm (which is the easiest way).

More details information can be found at: [Migrate an existing site to Platform.sh](https://docs.platform.sh/toolstacks/php/drupal/migrate-existing-site/)

Comment: Thanks Kenorb, please could you explain how to use drush and git. I have tried it but I couldn't use it. I am developing websites on machine which has Windows 8.1 operating system.

Comment: @TanmayKadam There are many ways to install drush on Windows. Try [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/9856/1908), [here](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/), [here](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush). If you don't have git, install from [here](http://git-scm.com/download/win). Then add these apps to your system PATH, so you can use them from terminal. After that initialize empty git repo as described in the last link of that post. If you stuck on some error, it's better if you search or ask another specific question, as it's not possible to cover all possibilities in few comments.

Comment: @kenorb Can you tell me how can I download website from platform.sh to my computer? Is there any click and download through UI method?

Comment: @Umair I haven't used _platform.sh_, so I'm not sure, however feel free to ask a new question.